I can't zip symbolic linked files with PHP
I have a cPanel Linux server running LiteSpeed ​​Web Server. There are constant photo uploads on a hosting on this server. However, the site is growing a little more every day and I am having problems with backups.
I thought of moving the photos from previous years to a location outside the hosting area and preventing unnecessary backups every day. I created a folder outside and gave access from the hosting area with a symbolic link. There is no problem on the web server side. The photos are displayed on the site.
However, sometimes users want to create a report and download old files as a zip. I cannot include files accessed with a symbolic link in a zip with PHP.
I tried running zip with exec instead of PHP's zip function.
I added open_basedir to php.ini.
I added "Options +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch" to .htaccess.
However, I could not succeed.
Is it possible to do something like this without compromising the security of the server?
My PHP code:
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open("test.zip", ZipArchive::CREATE);

$zip->addFile('/home/mysite/public_html/files/photo1.jpg', 'photo1.jpg');
$zip->addFile('/home/mysite/public_html/myPhotos/photo2.jpg', 'photo2.jpg');
$zip->addFile('/backup/myPhotos/photo3.jpg', 'photo3.jpg');

$zip->close();

When I run this code, the only file in the zip file is the photo1.jpg file under the files folder, which is a real folder.
/home/mysite/public_html/files is a real folder
/home/mysite/public_html/myPhotos/ is a symbolic link from /backup/myPhotos.

If you want the files accessible to PHP, and outside of the document root, you might have to loosen your security a bit.  Restrictions are made to prevent the very kind of thing you're trying to do.

"I cannot include files accessed with a symbolic link in a zip with PHP." Why? Are you getting an explicit error? If the web server can serve them, they should be readable to PHP. Give us an example of how your directory structure is laid out.

Of course I can afford to relax a bit.
My site folder is of course under home, and my other files are in the "/backup/myPhotos" folder. The permissions of the myPhotos folder are the same as the website's user.
No error message appears.
When I run this code, the only file in the zip file is the photo1.jpg file under the files folder, which is a real folder.

"When I run this code" What code? Post it.

Sorry, I wanted to add my code to the question. You can find the code in the rest of the question.

I can't speak to the symbolic link issue directly, but a hacky work around would be to use file_get_contents with ZipArchive::addFromString

@ChrisHaas That doesn't solve the problem, because file_get_contents() can't read the file due to open_basedir.

Since open_basedir() restricts the target of symlinks, I think you have to relax it. Another option is to put them in your document root, but use .htaccess in that directory to prevent direct linking to the files.

I changed the php.ini file to open_basedir = "/backup/myPhotos/"
Isn't that enough?

If it is in the document root, the cpanel backup system backs up these photos every night. Some photos are from 4-5 years ago and are in every backup. My goal is to move these unchanging files out of the site folder.

I'm trying to solve the problem with PHP, but cPanel has a solution for this problem.
If I want, I can exclude certain folders from backup.
"To exclude files or directories from an individual user’s backups, add the desired paths (relative to the user’s home directory) to the cpbackup-exclude.conf file in the user’s home directory, with one entry per line."
https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/backup/how-to-exclude-files-from-backups/

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
